# Jest unit test fails everytime Vue component gets mounted

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am currently trying to write some unit tests for my web application that I made with Nuxt, Vue and Vuetify. I decided to use the Jest framework and the `vue-test-utils` to write unit tests, but it seems like Jest or `vue-test-utils` refuses to mount my components.

### Example

Let’s take this very simple test where i `shallowMount` my component and see if the component renders a `div`:

```
require("jsdom-global")();

import AlbumHeader from "@/components/Album/AlbumHeader";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";

describe("AlbumHeader.vue", () => {
  it("renders a div", () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(AlbumHeader);
    expect(wrapper.contains("div")).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

When I run this unit test it always fails with the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined

I feel like the problem has something to do with Vuetify. But even after creating new Vuetify instances in my test and creating a `localVue` I still cannot get it to pass the test. I feel like I have read every article on this topic and none of them seem to help. This is also the first time I use this framework so I really do not have a clue where this problem takes place.

I hope someone can explain to me what i am doing wrong and how i can fix it, i would really appreciate that.

Comment: I see `shallowMount` instead of `mount`. What is the content of  AlbumHeader ?

Comment: If your component consists of other components, then you might need to stub your components or tell your test not to mount them. Otherwise it will try to import them and fails while doing so. In case it has base components, they need to be mounted for the test too.